# Pure Birth Question. Find the probability that the population at time $t$ is an odd # given it starts at $0$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, birth-death-process

Here is the question.

Consider a pure birth process $\{X(t) : t ≥ 0\}$ with birth parameters $\lambda_{2n} = α>0$ and $\lambda_{2n+1} =β>0$ for $n∈N$. Compute $Pr\{X(t) \text{ is odd } \mid X(0)=0\}$ for $t≥0$.

I am aware that the transitional probability equations for a pure birth process are:
$$ P_{ii}(t) = e^{-\lambda_{i} t} $$
$$ P_{ij}(t) = \lambda_{j-1} e^{-\lambda_{j} t} \int_{0}^{t} e^{\lambda_{j}s}P_{i,(j-1)}(s)ds, \quad (j > i)  $$

I'm pretty sure the transitional probability equations i listed above are what I have to use to start this problem, but I am not sure how to use them. Any insight to this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let $Y(t)=0$ if $X(t)$ is even and $Y(t)=1$ if $X(t)$ is odd, then $(Y(t))$ is a Markov chain on $\{0,1\}$ with known transition rates and you are asking for $P(Y(t)=1\mid Y(t)=0)$. Any idea to compute this?

Comment: Yea, I got it. Thank you for providing that information. I can basically use the Kolmogorov forward equations to solve for P(Y(t)=1∣Y(t)=0).